# soft delete imlementation Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a Addon class. When deleting its entity, I want to keep the record in the database, but hide it in queries.

With following implementation I run into an exception:

```
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE addon SET active IS FALSE WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "active = false")
public class Addon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;
    private String name;
    private int amount;
    private int minimalAmount;
    @OneToMany
    private Set<HandOver> handOvers;
    private boolean active;

    public Addon(){
         this.setAmount(0);
         this.active = true;
    }

    @PreRemove
    public void deleteAddon() {
        this.setActive(false);
    }
}
```

The delete method:

```
private void deleteAddon(){
        Addon toBeDeleted = chooseAddon();

        Session s = MainController.getSession();
        try {
            s.beginTransaction();
            s.remove(toBeDeleted);
            s.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            s.getTransaction().rollback();
            System.err.println("An error occured. Addon has not been deleted: " + e);
        }
    }
```

The exception:

```
Led 17, 2019 3:45:44 ODP. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
Led 17, 2019 3:45:44 ODP. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS FALSE WHERE id = 3' at line 1
Led 17, 2019 3:45:44 ODP. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Led 17, 2019 3:45:44 ODP. org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]

An error occured. Addon has not been deleted: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

And the Query (with "show_sql" = true in hibernate config) is:

```
Hibernate: delete from Addon_HandOver where Addon_id=?
Hibernate: UPDATE addon SET active IS FALSE WHERE id = ?
```

I'm using Hibernate 5 and MySQL 8.

Comment: I'd say it should be `active IS FALSE` instead of `active FALSE` and `SET active = FALSE` (true literal) instead of `SET active = 'FALSE'` (string value "FALSE", though MySQL most likely is able to convert that correctly).

Comment: The same exception is still raised.

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL? It should be logged as DEBUG for `org.hibernate.SQL`. Btw, if you want to filter inactive addons I'd further say that the where clause should be `active is TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write this: @Where(clause = "active='false'"), or true if active = true means a visibile record ;).

Comment: The program gets a step further, but then another exception is raised. I've added the exception and Query to the question.

Comment: Why do you get this query: "UPDATE addon SET active IS FALSE WHERE id = ?"

It should be : "UPDATE addon SET active = FALSE WHERE id = ?", so write this:

@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE addon SET active = FALSE WHERE id = ?")